# for making the database of sting

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

To change all these variable in database and store on database system on python

```
self.Roll_No = StringVar()
    self.First_Name = StringVar()
    self.Last_Name = StringVar()
    self.Phone_Number = StringVar()
    self.Department = StringVar()
    self.Email_Id = StringVar()
    self.Science_Marks = StringVar()
    self.Math_Marks = StringVar()
    self.Opt_Marks = StringVar()
    self.Total_Marks = StringVar()
    self.Search_Roll_No = StringVar()

    self.Drop_Down = StringVar()
    self.body()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You've created a bunch of variables, but nothing more.

Comment: I need to change this variable into the database form like sqlite or mysql

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to insert these string vars into a database. There's no need to change it into the database form as they're strings.

Assuming you're using sqlite3; `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (self.Roll_No.get(), self.First_Name.get(), self.Last_Name.get()))`
A `conn.commit` will probably be needed in the line after.